# If else condition in array

Tags: php, arrays

Hello i am trying to add if else statement in array().
here is my code

---

```
$excelData = array(
            $users->name,
            $users->first_name . ' ' . $organization->last_name,
            $users->user_email,
            date('d M y', $timestamp),
            if ($users->amount == NULL) {echo 0;} else { $users->amount; } ,
            if($users->coupon_code == NUll) { echo "No Coupon Code";}else {$users->coupon_code;} ,
            
            );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If/else structures are not meant to be used in-line like that.  They don't produce a value, but rather they perform an operation.  What you're looking to do is have a single expression which produces a value.  The [ternary conditional operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) can be used for that.  (Scroll down on that link to the section titled "Ternary Operator".)

For example, this expression produces a value:

```
$users->amount == NULL ? 0 : $users->amount
```

It will evaluate to either `0` or `$users->amount` based on the condition.  So in your code you would have:

```
$excelData = array(
    $users->name,
    $users->first_name . ' ' . $organization->last_name,
    $users->user_email,
    date('d M y', $timestamp),
    $users->amount == NULL ? 0 : $users->amount,
    $users->coupon_code == NULL ? "No Coupon Code" : $users->coupon_code
);
```

Comment: Ty so much sir.